# Alternative Solution to repeated digit worked example in chapter 8, KNK C Programming (Arrays & Boolean Values)

Tags: arrays, c, boolean

I am dealing with my attempted solution to a worked through problem of Chapter 8 in KNK's C Programming, A Modern Approach. I understand the answer they have proposed but would like to know why my one is wrong. I am stumped...

I am trying to write a program using arrays and the getchar() function to read a positive number and check whether it has repeated digits.

My program uses Boolean values to keep track of which digits appear in a number. The array named `digit_seen` is indexed from 0 to 9 to correspond to the 10 possible digits. Initially every element of the array is `false`.

I would *like* to write a program which, when given a number n, examines n's digits one at a time, from left to right. Storing each examined digit into the `digit` variable and then using it as an index into `digit_seen`. If `digit_seen[digit]` is true then `digit` appears at least twice in n. However if  `digit_seen[digit]` is false then `digit` has not been seen before and the program will then update `digit_seen[digit]` to true and keep on going.

Here is my imperfect code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  bool digit_seen[10] = {false};
  int digit;
  printf("Enter a positive number: ");

  while((digit = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(digit_seen[digit])
      break;

     digit_seen[digit] = true;
  }

  if(digit == EOF)
    printf("No repeated digit\n");
  else
    printf("Repeated digit\n");
}
```

Let me briefly explain why I (clearly incorrectly) think it should work. Suppose I type in the number 12 (i.e. n=12). Then `getchar()` takes 1, puts it in `digit`. Note that 1 != EOF, so the while loop is executed. We also see that `digit_seen[digit]` is false so the if statement is never executed and now we assign  `digit_seen[digit]` to true (i.e. the number 1 has been 'seen' now).

The exact process is repeated for the next digit 2. Then all the possible digits have been scanned and we get to EOF. So we assign digit = EOF. At this point the while loop is not executed. We go to the if statement following the while loop, see that it is indeed true and print the words "No repeated digit".

Now suppose instead I type in the number 22 instead of 12 (i.e. n=22). By the time we read the 2 digit for the second time `digit_seen[digit]` is *already*
true, so we break out of the while loop. We then encounter `if(digit == EOF)` and note that in the case where we are *breaking* out of the while loop (instead of the argument in the while's parenthesis being false) `digit` must have an integer value between 0 and 9 respectively. Yet EOF is stored as -1 on the computer. So the `if(digit == EOF)` is not executed, instead the else clause is executed and we have the program correctly telling us that a "Repeated digit" has been typed.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here? My output is always just "Repeated digit"? Further I would like to add that this is a worked example that KNK provides a solution for BUT the solution does not involve getchar(). It involves scanf() then uses modulo (%) and divide(/) operations to analyse the number's digits from right to left. I understand their solution but I am not content with understanding their alternative approach and not seeing where I failed. I find it curious they didn't use getchar() as this was my first instinct before looking at their solution. Is there a way to solve the problem using my proposed method, by analysing n's digits as they're typed? Or does it require a different approach like the one in the book?

As a self-taught programmer with no one else to ask these sorts of questions any elucidation would be very generous.

ANSWER:

After having taken your considerations on board I am posting my "alternative answer". One small tweak was all that was needed. I am now *extra* aware of what getchar() does and the ASCII Table. Not that I had a good reason not to be before. I would urge anyone reading to compare with KNK should be they curious.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  bool digit_seen[10] = {false};
  int  digit;
  printf("Enter a positive number: "); 

  while((digit = getchar()) != '\n') {
    digit -= '0';
    if(digit_seen[digit])
      break; 
  
     digit_seen[digit] = true;
  }
    
  if(digit == '\n')
    printf("No repeated digit\n");
  else
    printf("Repeated digit\n");
}
```

Comment: This! This is how you write a beginner question!

Comment: Appreciate the kind words! If a stranger is going to take the time out of their day to try and help me the very least I can do is try my best to express myself as clearly as possible. This online community has been nothing but encouraging to me. I appreciate that no one learns to code overnight. I hope in future I can be knowledgable enough to start helping others and paying back.

Comment: ...and the way out of this trap is to printf out the value of 'digit' or use an actual debugger to inspect the value.  Note well that developing software is very little to do with writing code - debugging is a more important skill.  Still, not a bad effort:)  There may well be a duplicate, but I'm not sure how I/you would easily find it.

Comment: That is a nice tip, I shall note it down!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getchar()` does not return a digit. It returns a code for a character.

In the code most commonly used for characters in C implementations, ASCII, the codes for the digit characters “0” through “9” are 48 through 57. Then `digit_seen[digit]` attempts to access the array using an index that is out of bounds of the array. This may result in accessing some part of memory that contains some unrelated value. If that value is non-zero, then `digit_seen[digit]` evaluates as true, and the `break;` is executed to leave the loop.

Then `digit == EOF` is not true, and “Repeated digit” is printed.

First, after getting a character with `getchar`, test whether it is a digit character using the `isdigit` function declared in `<ctype.h>`. If it is a digit character, convert it to a digit (0-9) using `digit -= '0';`. Then you can use it as an index into the array.

If it is not a digit character, you might ignore it or print a warning to the user. For example, “white space” characters (detected using the `isspace` function) may be ignored. This includes the new-line character that is generated when the user presses enter or return.

Comment: Also, you should break on `\n`, not EOF

Comment: Also, a fairly portable fix is `digit - '0'`

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you for patiently reading and clearly explaining. The ```<ctype.h> ``` has not been properly explained at this point. I suppose that as I learn more and more C, trivial questions like mine are less likely to come up in the first place... In any case thanks!

Comment: @tommie997: You can test whether a character code is a digit with `'0' <= digit && '9' <= digit`. Do not try that with letters. It works because the C standard requires character codes for digits to be consecutive, so they run from `'0'` (the code for “0”) to `'9'` (the code for “9”). The C standard does not make that requirement for letters; their codes can be non-consecutive.